# Few level enumerate across few rows in table

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate

I would like to create result like below:

[image]

First I was trying to do it using `tabbing`, but it doesn't work inside `enumerate`. So I found that it can work with table.

How can I do this?

----- EDIT ------

Here is my preamble and packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

----- EDIT 2 ------

Thanks to @A.Ellett for very good answer to my question. Additionally I would like to add headers to this columns like on the picture:

[image]

Comment: Which document class and packages are you using? Can you make a simple one enumerate environment long compilable example? The reason I'm asking is because depending on the packages you use we can avoid package clashes.

Comment: I've edited my question by adding my preambule and packages that I am using. I hope that it is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{tablerowcounter}
\newcommand{\mytablerow}{\stepcounter{tablerowcounter}\theenumi.\arabic{tablerowcounter}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Object \par
  \begin{tabular}{clll}
  \mytablerow  & Name & abcd & bcdf\\
  \mytablerow  & ABC  & xyz  & zyx \\
  \end{tabular}
\item File \par
  \begin{tabular}{clll}\setcounter{tablerowcounter}{0}%%'
  \mytablerow  & Name & aaa  & bb \\
  \mytablerow  & ABC  & ccc  & ddd \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a more automated and slightly more flexible approach which isn't hardwired into the first level of an `enumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{tablerowcounter}
\makeatletter
\def\myenumilevel{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mytablerow}{%%'
  \stepcounter{tablerowcounter}%%'
  \arabic{\myenumilevel}.\arabic{tablerowcounter}.}
\newenvironment{mytablelist}[1]
  {\par\setcounter{tablerowcounter}{0}%'
   \begin{tabular}{#1}} 
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Object 
  \begin{mytablelist}{clll}
  \mytablerow  & Name & abcd & bcdf\\
  \mytablerow  & ABC  & xyz  & zyx \\
  \end{mytablelist}
\item File
  \begin{mytablelist}{clll}
  \mytablerow  & Name & aaa  & bb \\
  \mytablerow  & ABC  & ccc  & ddd \\
  \end{mytablelist}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**REGARDING HEADERS**

For your headers, I've taken a rather different approach.  I've dispensed with the `enumerate` environment and chosen to make everything part of a table.  That will prove to be problematic if the table must span multiple pages.  But then perhaps you can load the `longtable` package to allow you to do this.  But right now I don't see a nice clean way to maintain the previous answer and add headers as you've illustrated above.

Here's the new MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Two counters to keep track of categories and 
%% subcategories
\newcounter{mycategorycounter}
\newcounter{subcategorycounter}

\newcommand{\mytablerow}{%%'
  & \stepcounter{subcategorycounter}%%'
    \arabic{mycategorycounter}.\arabic{subcategorycounter}.}

\newcommand{\tableColumnTitles}[3]{%%'
  &\multicolumn{2}{l}{#1}&#2&#3 \\}
%% create the category names; rules are here to add open space
%% above and below entry.  I use `\rlap` to alow the category
%% name to apparently span multiply columns
\newcommand{\currentCategory}[1]
  {\rule{0pt}{3ex}%%'
   \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1pt}%%'
   \stepcounter{mycategorycounter}%'
   \arabic{mycategorycounter}. & \rlap{#1} \\
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl*{3}{p{1.5in}}}
\tableColumnTitles{ABCD}{CLASS}{CATEGORY}
\currentCategory{Object}
\mytablerow & Name & abcd & bcdf \\
\mytablerow & ABC  & xyz  & zyx  \\
\currentCategory{File}
\mytablerow & Name & aaa  & bb   \\
\mytablerow & ABC  & ccc  & ddd  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is very good answer to my question :) Thank you! Could you additionaly tell me how to add headers to this columns (it should be three columns: first should have number and text)

Comment: If you update your posted question to illustrate what you mean, I would not mind at all.

Comment: @kpater87 I've updated the answer